# Libusb Error:failed to set Configuration

Tags: usb, libusb, libusb-1.0

When I try to set a configuration by libusb_set_configuration after performing libusb_set_auto_detach_kernel_driver I am getting the following  error below. Can anyone tell me how I will be able to rectify the issue below?

Error:-
Kernel driver detached successfully.
Failed to set configuration, error: LIBUSB_TRANSFER_ERROR

Thanks in advance.